# Does there exists a Dot.Net 4.5 Async Timer

Tags: c#, .net

I'd like to have a timer where I can wait on with the await keyword. I was just curious if it exists?

Comment: There is an example of waiting against a delay here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, this was where I was looking for.

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable coding question with a straightforward technical answer; I see no reason to close it as "not a real question".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suspect you just want [`Task.Delay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.delay%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public async Task Foo()
{
    // Do some work
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    // Do some more work 5 seconds later
}
```